# Fitting model to data in matlab

Tags: matlab, model-fitting

i have some experimental data and a theoretical model which i would like to try and fit. i have made a function file with the model - the code is shown below

```
function [ Q,P ] = RodFit(k,C )
% Function file for the theoretical scattering from a Rod
% R = radius, L = length

R = 10; %  radius in Å
L = 1000; % length in Å
Q = 0.001:0.0001:0.5;

fun = @(x)  (   (2.*besselj(1,Q.*R.*sin(x)))./...
            (Q.*R.*sin(x)).*...
            (sin(Q.*L.*cos(x)./2))./...
            (Q.*L.*cos(x)./2)...
            ).^2.*sin(x);

P = (integral(fun,0,pi/2,'ArrayValued',true))*k+C;

end
```

with Q being the x-values and P being the y-values. I can call the function fine from the matlab command line and it works fine e.g. [Q,P] = RodFit(1,0.001) gives me a result i can plot using `plot(Q,P)`

But i cannot figure how to best find the fit to some experimental data. Ideally, i would like to use the optimization toolbox and lsqcurvefit since i would then also be able to optimize the R and L parameters. but i do not know how to pass (x,y) data to lsqcurvefit. i have attempted it with the code below but it does not work

```
File = 30; % the specific observation you want to fit the model to
ydata = DataFiles{1,File}.data(:,2)';
% RAdius = linspace(10,1000,length(ydata));
% LEngth = linspace(100,10000,length(ydata));
Multiplier = linspace(1e-3,1e3,length(ydata));
Constant = linspace(0,1,length(ydata));
xdata = [Multiplier; Constant]; % RAdius; LEngth;
L = lsqcurvefit(@RodFit,[1;0],xdata,ydata);
```

it gives me the error message:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in RodFit (line 15)
P = (integral(fun,0,pi/2,'ArrayValued',true))*k+C;
Error in lsqcurvefit (line 199)
        initVals.F = feval(funfcn_x_xdata{3},xCurrent,XDATA,varargin{:});
Caused by:
Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. LSQCURVEFIT cannot      continue.
```

i have tried i) making all vectors/matrices the same length and ii) tried using `.*` instead. nothing works and i am giving the same error message

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated, whether it is suggestion regading what method is should use, suggestions to my code or something third.

**EDIT TO ANSWER Osmoses:**
A really good point but i do not think that is the problem. just checked the size of the all the vectors/matrices and they should be alright

```
>> size(Q)
ans =
       1        1780

>> size(P)
ans =
       1        1780

>> size(xdata)
ans =
       2        1780

>> size([1;0.001]) - the initial guess/start point for xdata (x0)
ans =
       2     1

>> size(ydata)
ans =
       1        1780
```

**UPDATE**

I think i have identified the problem. the function RodFit works fine when i specify the input directly e.g. `[Q,P] = RodFit(1,0.001);`.

however, if i define x0 as `x0 = [1,0.001]` i cannot pass x0 to the function

```
>> x0 = [1;0.001]

x0 =

1.0000
0.0010

>> RodFit(x0);
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in RodFit (line 15)
P = (integral(fun,0,pi/2,'ArrayValued',true))*k+C;
```

The same happens if i use `x0 = [1,0.001]`
clearly, matlab is interpreting x0 as input for `k` only and attempts to multiplay a vector of length(ydata) and a vector of length(x0) which obviously fails.

So my problem is that i need to code so that *lsqcurvefit* understands that the first column of xdata and x0 is the `k` variable and the second column of xdata and x0 is the `C` variable. According to the documentation - [Passing Matrix Arguments](http://www.mathworks.se/help/optim/ug/matrix-arguments.html) - i should be able to pass x0 as a matrix to the solver. The solver should then also pass the xdata in the same format as x0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried (that's sometimes the mistake) looking at the orientation of your input data (e.g. if xdata & ydata are both row/column vectors?). Other than that your code looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve some of the problems. One mistake in my code was that the objective function did not use of vector a variables but instead took in two variables - k and C. changing the code to accept a vector solved this problem

```
function [ Q,P ] = RodFit(X)
% Function file for the theoretical scattering from a Rod
% R = radius, L = length

% Q = 0.001:0.0001:0.5;
Q = linspace(0.11198,4.46904,1780);
fun = @(x)  (   (2.*besselj(1,Q.*R.*sin(x)))./...
           (Q.*R.*sin(x)).*...
           (sin(Q.*L.*cos(x)./2))./...
           (Q.*L.*cos(x)./2)...
           ).^2.*sin(x);

P = (integral(fun,0,pi/2,'ArrayValued',true))*X(1)+X(2);
```

with the code above, i can define x0 as `x0 = [1 0.001];`, and pass that into RodFit and get a result. i can also pass xdata into the function and get a result e.g. `[Q,P] = RodFit(xdata(2,:));`

Notice i have changed the orientation of all vectors so that they are now row-vectors and xdata has size `size(xdata) =  1780           2`

so i thought i had solved the problem completely but i still run into problems when i run lsqcurvefit. i get the error message

```
Error using RodFit
Too many input arguments.

Error in lsqcurvefit (line 199)
        initVals.F = feval(funfcn_x_xdata{3},xCurrent,XDATA,varargin{:});

Caused by:
Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. LSQCURVEFIT cannot     continue.
```

i have no idea why - does anyone have any idea about why Rodfit recieves to many input arguments when i call *lsqcurvefit* but not when i run the function manual using xdata?